# Computing Fourier Transforms in $L^2$.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

In our course, the Fourier transform of $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as,
$$\mathcal{F}(f) = \hat{f}(\zeta) = \int e^{-ix\zeta}f(x)dx.$$
Therefore, the inverse fourier transform is defined as,
$$\bar{\mathcal{F}}(f) = f(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{ix\zeta} \hat{f}(\zeta)d\zeta.$$

We have computed the Fourier transform of $f=1_{[-1,1]}$, which is,
$$\hat{f}(\zeta) = \frac{\sin(\zeta)}{\zeta}.$$

Now the goal is to compute the Fourier transform of the function $g(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}.$ I am not sure whether I am arguing correctly here.

Here is what I have done so far. We know that, 
$$\hat{f}(\zeta) =g(\zeta)\iff \mathcal{F}(f) = g\\ 
\implies f = (2\pi)^{-1}\bar{\mathcal{F}}(g)\\
\implies \bar{f} = (2\pi)^{-1}\overline{\overline{\mathcal{F}}(g)}\\ 
\implies (2\pi)\bar{f}=\hat{g}. $$

Thus we conclude that $\hat{g} = \frac{1}{2\pi}1_{[-1,1]}(x).$ Is this correct reasoning? I apologize for the non-standard notation, but I can't do much about it at this point.

Comment: Looks good. Note that your formula for the Fourier transofrm above only holds for $f\in L^1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The definition makes no sense in $L^2.$